# VBA Error: Object Variable or With Block variable not set

Tags: vba, excel, delete-row

I am new to VBA and am working on a Macro that will delete duplicate lines in a material tracking spreadsheet based off matching elements in 3 specific columns labeled: "Requisition Number", "Item", and "PO #".

However, when I try to set activate the first element in my requisition number using `ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, colReq.Column).Address()).Activate` I'm given the Error: Object Variable or With Block variable not set

The following is my full code:

```
Sub DeleteDuplicates()



    Dim sh As Worksheet
        Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Dim lastRow As Long

        lastRow = sh.Range("A1", sh.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count



    Dim colReq As Range
    Dim colItemReq As Range
    Dim colPO As Range
    Dim colType As Range

    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(1)
        Set colReq = .Find(What:="Requisition Number", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        Set colItemReq = .Find(What:="Item", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        Set colPO = .Find(What:="PO #", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        Set colType = .Find(What:="PO #", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    End With


    Dim current As String
    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, colReq.Column).Address()).Activate
    Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
        current = ActiveCell.Address
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
        Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
            If (ActiveSheet.Range(current).Value = ActiveCell.Value) And _
            ((ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row - 1, colItemReq.Column).Address).Value) = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, colItemNumber).Value)) And _
            ((ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row - 1, colPO).Address).Value) = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, colPO).Value)) And (ActiveCell.Value <> "Shipping Notification") Then
                ActiveSheet.Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Delete
            Else
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
            End If
        Loop
        ActiveSheet.Range(current).Offset(1, 0).Activate
    Loop



End Sub
```

Comment: Take a look at the [RemoveDuplcates method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193823.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! I actually was using that method at first but I also only want the row to be deleted if it doesn't say "Shipping Notification", which I couldn't figure out how to do with the RemoveDuplicates method

Comment: I guess `colPO` should be `colPO.Column` in the line that raises the error (in both places)

Comment: What does colReq contain at the time you are trying to execute that line?  Hint: when you stop in debug mode, in the immediate window enter `?colReq.Address` and see if you get a cell address.  If not, then the problem is in your `.Find` statement